# Perl: how do I read a file from a subdirectory?

Tags: perl

I'm really new to Perl, so excuse me if I missed an obvious answer. I will appreciate all help.

I'm trying to read a file that is located in a subdirectory, so I can extract some information, and print the information into a new file.

I know how to read a file in the current directory (and print into a new file):

```
open IN, "$file_name" or die "No such file: !$";
open OUT, ">$new_file_name" or die " No such file: !$";

while (<IN>) {
print OUT $_;
}
```

but how do I do this to a file that is located in a subdirectory?

Many thanks,

Nika

EDIT:

Thank-you all very very much! I've solved the problem!

Comment: Have you tried placing the full or relative path to the file on $file_name?

Comment: Aaahhh, yes that works. I tried this before, and it didn't, and now I know why. My file name includes a period: "birdseed.report". So when I when wrote `"./subdirectory/birdseed.report"`, it messed it up.

Would you know how to include a period in the file name? `"./subdirectory/birdseed\.report"` doesn't work..

Comment: @user2759776 Period `.` is not a meta character in a path. Your error has nothing to do with your file name, but rather that you think `.` refers to the parent directory, when it is in fact `..`. And also, surely it is not news for you that many/most files actually do contain periods, since they have extensions? `news.txt`, `foo.html`, `home.php`?

Comment: I am an idiot, sorry about that. Of course the period shouldn't be the problem. Then I'm really not sure what the difference between "birdseed.report" is, and another file. I get the following message when I try to use `./subdirectory/birdseed.report`: `readline() on closed filehandle IN at My_program.pl`. So the filehandle seems to close. Any idea why it would react like this?

Answer (score 3):

`open` takes a *path*, so

```
my $file_name = 'subdir/file.ext';
```

Here's your code with many improvements:

```
open my $IN, '<', $in_qfn
    or die "Can't open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n";

open my $OUT, '>', $out_qfn
    or die "Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n";

while (<$IN>) {
    print $OUT $_;
}
```

I'd actually use ARGV and STDOUT for maximum flexibility if possible.

```
while (<>) {
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much! All these answers are great, and I've discovered why they haven't been working. I have a period in my file's name ("birdseed.report), so when I say `./subdirectory/birdseed.report`, it doesn't work. A backslash, as in `./subdirectory/birdseed\.report` doesn't fix the problem..

Comment: What do you mean by "I say `./subdirectory/birdseed.report`"? Maybe the current work directory isn't what you think it is? Does it work if you pass an absolute path (e.g. `/home/ikegami/foo/birdseed.report`?)

Comment: @ikegami I think he thinks that `.` is the subdirectory, the parent directory of the current directory. So what he'd really need is `../birdseed.report`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. It works both ways, with `./subdirectory/file_name` and with an absolute path, so long as I use another file with no period in it's name. My problem is that my file name "birdseed.report" doesn't seem to be recognised. E.g. if I use `./subdirectory/file.txt` all is well. But not if I use `./subdirectory/birdseed.report`.

Comment: @user2759776 You see no period in the file name `file.txt`? Your deduction is wrong, the period does not matter.

Comment: Crap, off course, that was incredibly stupid.. Sorry about that. Then I'm really not sure why my file isn't recognised. When I use "birdseed.report" instead of another file name, I get the error message `readline() on closed filehandle IN at My_program.pl`. Any suggestions as to why the filehandle seems to close?

Comment: @user2759776 You cannot get that error if you use the `open` statement you showed above: `open IN, "$file_name" or die "No such file: !$"`. That error indicates that the `open` failed, or that the file handle was closed. As for why birdseed.report fails, perhaps you are not reading the directory you think. Also, the error variable is `$!` and not `!$`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the $! correction. I'm sure I'm reading the right directory, as the code works with another file in the same directory. Which is why I thought maybe the problem was in the name, and somehow stupidly assumed it was the period..

Comment: @user2759776 Well, its difficult to say what the problem is without seeing your code or your directory structure. I have personally made the mistake of thinking I was reading the right file, when it turned out it was a file with the same name in a different place. Such as, thinking I was reading `foo/foo.txt`, when in fact I was reading `foo.txt` who just happened to exist.

Comment: Well, thank-you anyway. Whilst everything could be, I doubt it. I'm using a direct path now, and all I do is exchange the name of the file. It works fine with the other 2 files present in the subdirectory, but not with "birdseed.report". But at least my primary question was answered, now I'm going to tinker and see if I can figure out this particular case.

Comment: My first question went unanswered. Please answer by providing code that demonstrates this problem. Code you actually ran.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question. I have since solved the problem. The answer was of course stupidly easy: I didn't realise that that file needed a .txt extension at the end. Thank-you so much for all the other effort.

Answer (score 3):

There are two obvious ways:

1. Access the file by its full path name, i.e. the value of `$file_name` must be something like `directoryname/filename.txt` or you write `"directoryname/$filename"` in your first line of code.
2. Change the working directory. That is, use the Perl `chdir` function to change the working directory before accessing the file: `chdir "directoryname";` Keep in mind that this affects all subsequent file systems operations. If you want to go back, use `chdir "..";`.

In either case, it is very helpful to familiarize yourself with the concept of working directory, special directory names (`.` and `..`), the path separator `/`, relative and absolute paths and how file systems work in general.

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a full path to the directory. you can use the pwd command to get the full path if you are in the directory where file is located. Note, you should always use the qualified/full path to files because you never know from where the script might be invoked. (it's just good programming practice)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'your_full/path/sub_dir/data.txt';
if (open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)) {
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
chomp $row;
print "$row\n";
}
} else {
warn "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables (or strings) may contain the relative path to the file so simply say

```
open IN, "foo/$file1"
```

Oh and [use 3-argument open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give the name of the file in the subdirectory. Use the forward slash to separate the directory from the sub directory.

Here's your program written in a bit more modern fashion:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

my $file_name = "path/to/file";
my $new_file_name = "path/to/new/file";

open my $in_fh, "<" $file_name;
open my $out_fh, ">", $new_file_name;

while my $line ( <$in_fh> ) {
    print {$out_fh} $line;
}
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

- `use strict;` requires you to declare your variables which can save you a lot of hassle. For example, you say `$foo` on place and `$Foo` (with a capital *F*) in another. With `use strict;`, Perl will catch these errors for you. You declare a variable with `my` or `our`. 99% of the time, you will use `my`.
- `use warnings;` turns on all sorts of warnings. For example, you are attempting to do something with a variable that is undefined.
- `use autodie` automatically will kill your Perl script in many circumstances. For example, you can't open or close a file. Or, what if the disk is full, and your `print` statement can't print to the file?
- `use feature qw(say);` allows you to use `say` instead of `print`. The `say` command will automatically add a NL to the end of the line for you which is a lot more convenient than it sounds.
- Use *three parameter* `open` and `close`, and use variable names for the file handle. This makes passing the file handle easier to do to subroutines.
- Don't use the default `$_` when you don't have to. There are many issues with using it (which I am not going to get into right now. It really doesn't add clarity to the program, and will many times get you into trouble.
- Use `close` when you finish with a file.

You should get a good book on [Modern Perl](http://modernperl.net/books/evaluating-a-good-perl-book.html). For example, in your program, I could have done this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Copy;    # Adds a `copy` command to Perl

use constant {     # Adds the concept of a constant to Perl
    IN_FILE   =>  'path/to/file',
    OUT_FILE  =>  '/paht/to/new/file',
};

copy IN_FILE, OUT_FILE;   # That's it!
```

No need to open files. No need to use loops. The `copy` command will do it for you.

These *modules* like `File::Copy` are available in the standard installations of Perl. You need to learn about them, so you can use them. This is why you should get a good book and go through it.

Have fun with Perl, and please learn the right way of doing things. It makes Perl a much easier language to use and learn.

Comment: You should not spread vague rumours about `$_`. There are no "issues" with it, it is perfectly safe to use, and it will not get you into trouble. If you can't give a reason it should not be used, then perhaps that is because there are no such reasons.

Comment: The problem is `$_` is global in scope and is always in `main. Anything can change `$_` without you knowing about it. Using `$_` will work about 90% of the time. Maybe even 99% of the time. It's that last 1% that will bite you, and probably at a time when everything is on the line. And, for what? So we can write `for (<@values>)` instead of `for (my $value = <@value>)`? `$_` was suppose to make Perl more _English like_, but it doesn't really improve clarity or make the program run any faster. Might as well get into the habit of using a variable instead of depending upon `$_`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `for my $value (@value)`. And you are wrong in this case. `$_` is localized when used by `for`, `grep` and such functions, not global. I agree that its scope should be limited, and it potentially is a source of error (although you would have to try rather hard). What you should do is mention that in your answer, however, rather than give ominous and vague warnings. Fear without knowledge is not healthy, you know.

Comment: I actually answered a question about this recently. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18569458/725418).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it certainly helps a lot. I know I should really go through some good books on Perl, unfortunately I'm doing a rather short internship, with little time to really immerse my self in it. Which is why sites like these, and all these answers really help, letting me pick stuff up on the fly.